# Status update on bulk elastic upload using helper

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to update a bunch of records in a single index, however i need the status if the update is successful or not. Reason is that the particular id may not be available in the index. This is how my code looks like, i dont get any output for "update_response" even though the records are being updated in my index. Shouldnt i be getting a " **It returns a tuple with summary information - number of successfully executed actions and either list of errors or number of errors if stats_only is set to True.**"

as per function definition at this page https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/helpers.html

```
es = config.createESConnection()
start_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
api_url = 'abcd'
parameters = { 
    "processed":False,
    "date":start_time
}
response = requests.get(api_url,params=parameters)
info= requests.get(api_url,params=parameters).json()['data']

es_data=[]
for i in range(len(info)):
    action = {
            "_index": "index",
            "_id" : info[i]['id'],
            "_op_type":"update",
            "doc":{"x" : info[i]['x']}
        }
    es_data.append(action)
    
update_response = helpers.bulk(es, es_data,stats_only =True)
print(update_response)
except Exception:
```

Answer (score 0):

okay so this is to help others, in case there is an error in helpers.bulk you need to enable raise_on_error=False, doing so will complete the updation on all the records, skipping the ones having error and then you get the return object.

so use this

```
update_response = helpers.bulk(es, es_data,raise_on_error=False)
```